# JSON en android "Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Tags: php, java

ESTOY INTENTANDO RECIBIR UN JSON EN MI APLICACION ANDROID PERO AL HACER LA PETICION AL PHP ME ARROJA EL MENSAJE "**"Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject**".
PARA DEPURAR UN POCO MI CODIGO LE QUITE TODA LA FUNCIONALIDAD Y SOLAMENTE DEJÉ LOS MENSAJES *TOAST* PARA SABER DONDE ESTA EL ERROR Y VI QUE EL PROGRAMA ME ESTÁ ENVIANDO DIRECTO AL MÉTODO `public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)` Y NO ENTIENDO POR QUE, ALGUIEN PUEDE AYUDARME?

AQUI DEJO MI CODIGO EN JAVA

```
public void CalendarLoadClient () {
    String URL = "https://ironwodcenter.000webhostapp.com/webServices/CalendarLoadClient.php";

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                //todo: YO NECESITO QUE EL PROGRAMA ENTRE AQUI
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Todo cool", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        //todo: EL PROGRAMA ME TRAE AQUI
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error en el Request" + error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
}
```

Y AQUI EL JSON QUE GENERA MI PHP

```
{"Client":[{"idClient":"1","name":"Javier","lastName":"Canche","eMail":"javier.canche@correo.com","userName":"admin","password":"admin","status":"0"}]}
```

Comment: El problema es que tu PHP no está emitiendo sólo un JSON, sino que está emitiendo esto también: `Notice: Undefined index: userName in /storage/ssd2/383/15249383/public_html/webServices/CalendarLoadClient.php on line 4`, puedes ir a la URL y verificarlo. Eso hace que tu JSON no sea válido. Debes corregir ese `Undefined index` para que tu JSON sea recibido limpiamente. Por favor, considera usar las minúsculas, es de mal gusto una pregunta totalmente en mayúscula. Pulsa en [edit] y mejora tu redacción. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice @A.Cedano, el problema realmente es el archivo `CalendarLoadClient.php` que no chequea la existencia de un indice:

> Notice: Undefined index: userName

Esto invalida los datos JSON con texto inesperado.

En alguna parte del archivo PHP se esta intentando obtener un valor de array con un indice `'userName'` inexistente. Tipicamente si lo obtienes de `$_GET`, deberia ser algo asi:

```
if (isset($_GET['userName'])) {
   // aqui puedes usar $_GET['userName'] sin warnings
}
```